# Using either jQuery or plain JavaScript to fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the first time I've ever using stackoverflow, so here I go.

I'm creating a website and currently, I have created buttons for the navigation. By default (the homepage) shows a slideshow using JavaScript and this is all contained within a div.

When I click, let's say the 'About Me' page, I want that div to fade out and another div to fade in which will contain an image and text.

Here's my code:

```
<body>
    <div id="top_wrapper">
        <a class="button navigation" id="homeBtn">Home</a>
        <a class="button navigation" id="aboutBtn">About Me</a>
        <a class="button navigation" id="coachBtn">Peronsal, Business and Professional Coaching</a>
        <a class="button navigation" id="successBtn">Success Stories</a>
        <a class="button navigation" id="workBtn">Community Work</a>
        <a class="button navigation" id="charityBtn">Charity</a>
        <a class="button navigation" id="contactBtn">Contact Me</a>
    </div>
    <div id="home">
        <div id="sliderFrame">
            <div id="slider">
                <img src="_images/_image01.jpg" />
                <img src="_images/_image02.jpg" />
                <img src="_images/_image03.jpg" />
                <img src="_images/_image04.jpg" />
                <img src="_images/_image05.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="border">
            <img src="_images/_border.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="aboutme">
        <div id="text">
            <p>This is the text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

In my example, I want that when the user clicks on the 'About Me' button, the div 'home' fades out and the div 'aboutme' fades in.

I've tried nearly all of the examples on stackoverflow as well as whatever the jQuery/JavaScript websites and Google could throw at me and no luck.

Comment: I thought this question is about performance "using either jQuery or plain JavaScript".

Answer (score 5):

One way could be to do it like so:

```
$('#aboutBtn').click(function(){
  $('#home').fadeOut(300);
  $('#aboutme').delay(400).fadeIn(300);
});
```

---

**Edit:** the solution above was more of a quick fix for an individual case, the solution below is the kind of thing you should do instead, especially when you have multiple anchors/divs.

[**Here's a working jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/25Px6/4/).

**HTML:**

```
<a class="buttonNav" target="1">Home</a>
<a class="buttonNav" target="2">About</a>
<a class="buttonNav" target="3">Success</a>


<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Home Div</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">About Div</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Success Div</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.targetDiv {
    display:none;
    color:red;
}

.targetDiv:nth-of-type(1) {
    display:block;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
   $('.buttonNav').click(function(){
       $('.targetDiv').fadeOut();
       $('#div'+ $(this).prop('target')).delay(400).fadeIn();
   });
});
```

This approach would be much cleaner for scaling usage of options, like in your case.

Comment: Why use a delay when you can just use the callback to `fadeOut`?

Comment: it would be beneficial to apply classes so you can specifically fade. Like add an active class on click so you can fade the current active class instead of making a specific handler for every instance - This comment is for the OP. I know Zenith knows this

Comment: +1, LOL, I just learned three new jQuery functions :) I was about to suggest messing around with `timeOut()`, `opacity`, and `filter: alpha(opacity)`.  Hmmm, NO, VoidKing, NO! I'm glad to see jQuery has introduced such an easy way to implement what probably is a common web-designer request.

Comment: Hi Zenith,

Firstly, thank you for commenting back so soon... it's most appreciated!

I tried your method, but unfortunately it didn't work :(

Maybe my concept may be wrong? I was hoping to have just one main web page with navigation buttons on, which will just fade the divs in and out within that one page. Is this possible?

Comment: @Mashy Please read my updated answer before accepting the other solution - my edit is far better performance wise, and you don't have to use events for seperate ID's unlike the other answer you commented on (you will end up with about 50 lines of code to write using that solution, instead of my 6 lines). It will slow your web-page down.

Answer (score 1):

You can `fadeout` the **home** div and in callback of this `fadeout` you can `fadein` the **about me** div. Somthing like this:

```
$('#aboutBtn').click(function(){
  $('#home').fadeOut('slow', function(){
     $('#aboutme').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Here is the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/j7Nuc/4/)**

Comment: I like Zenith's better, shows how you can set the milliseconds

Comment: @VoidKing .. Yes we can use milliseconds also in place of 'slow'.

Comment: Hi Raman,

Firstly, thank you for commenting back so soon mate, it's most appreciated!

I also tried your method but it didn't work... When I click on the buttons (i.e. aboutBtn), it didn't do anything. Not sure what to do :(

Comment: @Mashy... its working absolutely fine for me... Have you included the click event in document ready function? Check out this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/j7Nuc/4/

Comment: Hi Raman, Just wanted to say thank you very much as this worked! I've decided to go with Shlomi's coding as I can fit everything (hopefully) together. Thank you very much mate... It's truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JHN33/)

This example will allow you using the same div as a container for all links...

Note that you should add a href for your link tags.

Have fun.

jquery:

```
$('#aboutme').hide();

$('#aboutBtn').click(function(){
$('#home').fadeOut('slow', function(){ 
    $('#aboutme').text('about me text!!!').fadeIn('slow', function(){ });
});
});
$('#homeBtn').click(function(){
$('#home').fadeOut('slow', function(){ 
    $('#aboutme').text('home text button text!!!').fadeIn('slow', function(){ });
});
});
//add other click events for each link.
```

**EDIT:** Tune up - and save time

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujuSg/)

Now you should set only an array key as the same id of the relevant link and type in his text!

have fun

Comment: Hi Shlomi, Just wanted to say thank you very much as this worked! I've decided to go with your method as it allows me to use the same div as a container for all of the links (as you mentioned).

Comment: Ok have fun - you still can accept the answer see the Tune up in my edit